# Element Not visible Error in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, protractor, element

I have a checkbox in the UI and I get the error "ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible" when I try to check that checkbox, but when I try to capture it in the console of chrome developer tools, i am able to capture and click the element. Anyone faced the same issue? or any solutions. TIA

Comment: have you tried waiting for it to be visible first, using expected conditions?

Comment: or try using the click method from https://github.com/hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper which builds in waiting for the element to be displayed before clicking.

Comment: @JeremyKahan tried but seems not working :S

Comment: What message does Hetzner cloud give in the console? Something like tried 3 times and could not find it? Another approach would be to bypass some of the error checking and just use executescript to click it. Like browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(loc)); Or if the message is actually right, you might need a browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element(loc)) after which the regular routine (maybe after a wait) would work.

Answer (score 1):

Use Expected Conditions, you have API documentation [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions).

```
    var wantedElement = element(by.id("idlocator"));
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(wantedElement), 60000, "Element is not visible").then(function() {
            element.click();
    });
```